# which scripting language in the url part use : and ? to request or get info from the server side?

Tags: programming-languages, http-headers

familiar with the example below?

eg:

http://www.example001.com/browse:tags?word=red

elaborate further using the : and ? and =

:xxxx?xxxx=xxxx

and suggestions on scripting language that can combine together with regular expressions and tag with @  or hash etc

thanks

Comment: Please clarify your question. This is not a scripting language. it's just a URL with a path and querystring which you would need to parse on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a link that is processed by a PHP script: http://php.net/manual/de/reserved.variables.get.php

`?` usually indicates the beginning of the arguments.

`=` means that argument `word` gets `red` as value. This can then be read in PHP via `$_GET['word']`

I'm not sure what the `:` is. Maybe it gets converted internally via [`modrewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html) or something.

Comment: other also not familiar with the :

here reply I got from others:

  but a few languages except those arguments php for example could retrieve and process. I do not know about the : though

Comment: Ok for modrewrite, but for the rest it could be processed by almost anything, it's just a URL...

Answer (score 0):

It is not a scripting language, it is a URL. The HTTP server at www.example001.com will see this query: `GET /browse:tags?word=red`

It is up to that server to interpret this string and build its response accordingly.